# Schroedinger's Disk

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a desktop using a 128GB SSD. Because there is not so much space, I also have a slower 1TB HD. This drive consists of one single Ext2 partition. For unknown reasons, I always have to mount it manually after booting my machine. Several attempts, such as

- Editing `/etc/rc.local`:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  mount /dev/sdb1 /home/max/files
  exit 0
  ```

  and making it executable;
- Changing `/etc/fstab` to include the following line:

  ```
  /dev/sdb1 /home/max/files auto defaults 0 0
  ```
- Using the GUI (with a program called *Disks*)

Have all the same result: In the file manager, the drive is shown to be mounted, but there is only as much free space listed as I have on the SSD. If I open the terminal and use `lsblk`, the HD is listed as mounted. However, if I type

```
sudo umount /home/max/files
```

I get

```
umount: /home/max/files: not mounted.
```

Typing

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home/max/files
```

correctly mounts the drive, which is then required to be done every time I start up my PC.

The HD is somehow displaying a superposition of *mounted* and *not mounted* state properties simultaneously... Hence the title of the question.

What else can I try to mount the HD on startup i.e. to make it collapse to the *mounted* state at startup already?

edit

List block devices outputs

```
[max@packmule ~]$ lsblk -f | grep sdb1
└─sdb1                ext2        Samsung 7ab4c1ac-21ca-671a-9f12-5439ad3ac613   /home/max/files
```

Comment: Do you use a separate home partition?

Comment: @user68186 Setting `UUID=7ab4c1ac-21ca-671a-9f12-5439ad3ac613 /home/max/files ext2 defaults 0 2` does not help... same outcome as before.

Comment: @danzel No, the SSD consists of 2 partitions, one mounted at `/boot` and the other at '/' (root)

Comment: Rename /etc/local.rc to `/etc/rc.local` as /etc/rc.local is the last init script to be run.

Comment: How is the 1TB hard drive connected to the system?

Comment: @AndrewBeals Typo, sorry. I tried `rc.local`. Just edited my post.

Comment: Please add output of `lsblk -f | grep sdb1` to your question.

Comment: @AndrewBeals The drive is connected via SATA.

Comment: When you use rc.local do you see any errors in journalctl output related to it or the drive ?